# Django: ModelChoiceField remove default --------- choice

Tags: django, forms

How do i remove the default --------- choice from ModelChoiceField?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `empty_label=None`

`field2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=..., empty_label=None)`

Please check the doc for [ModelChoiceField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)

Comment: Also note that if the field is required and has a default value, the empty option will automatically be removed.