# ModelChoiceField , removing the blank choice

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to get rid of the "-------------" choice Django adds in a select input representing a Foreign Key on a ModelForm

It's [been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868211/django-modelchoicefield-remove-default-choice) that you can use the `empty_label=none` option, but I have a ModelForm, not a regular form and overriding the field is not allowed.

I know that I can override the `__init__()` method of the ModelForm in order to modify a ModelChoiceField's queryset using

```
self.fields['my_foreign_key'].queryset = ....
```

But this would be really ugly, as this happens over +10 foreign_keys on the "Main" model, and there's more than a Modelform based on this model

The whole context :

- each one of these foreign_key points to the same kind of models : they are particular lists of choices, many models to ease their modification via the admin.
- all these models are related to the Main model via a "to_field=code" relation, based on a Charfield which contains a three-letter code (hey, not my fault, I had to use a legacy MS Access DB), this CharField has the `blank=True, unique=True` options, so I could, for each list, create a `"---No information yet---"` record which has, you bet, a blank value instead of a three letter code...

The situation is now : I get a select input field with two "blank value" choices : the django one and mine, one after the other.
I just miss a 'empty_label=none` option here too...

Comment: I think you can redefine/overwrite the field. I do this to change a DateTime model field into a forms TimeField (and add an extra field of DateField). Then I override the clean() method of the form to combine the date and time fields.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to remove the blank choice for all `ModelChoiceField` you could do something like..

```
class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        modelchoicefields = [field for field_name, field in self.fields.iteritems() if
            isinstance(field, forms.ModelChoiceField)]

        for field in modelchoicefield:
            field.empty_label = None
```

But that would replace all `ModelChoiceField`s, so maybe something more fine grained like:

```
for fieldname in ('field1','field2','field3','field4','field5','field6'):
    self.fields[fieldname].empty_label = None
```

Certainly easier than the `__init__` overwrite you mentioned!

## Update from Moritz

You can use 2017+ use:

```
forms.ModelChoiceField(... empty_label=None
```

Comment: That works great Yuji, wish I could click ten times on the UP arrow. ModelForms are not so closed I thought after all

Comment: You can do the following now:
```forms.ModelChoiceField(... empty_label=None)```

Comment: @Moritz nice. added.